# complex sql query from 4 tables

Tags: sql, count, left-join, min

I am developing an online travel guide with a lot of hotels. Each hotel belongs to a specific category, has a lot room types and each of hotel room has different price per season. I want to make a complex query from 4 tables in order to get the total number of hotels per hotels category **where the minimum price of each hotel rooms is between 2 values which are adjusted by a slider**.

My tables look like:

- **Categories**
- id_category
- category_name

---

- **Hotels**
- id_hotel
- hotel_name
- category_id
- ......

---

- **hotels_room_types**
- id_hotels_room_type
- hotel_id
- room_type_id
- ......

---

- **hotels_room_types_seasons**
- hotels_room_types_id
- season_id
- price
- ......

for example some values of category_name are: Hotels, apartments, hostels
I would like my results table to have two fields like the following:

**Hotels  32

apartments   0

hostels 5**

I tried the following query but it returns the total number of all hotels per category, not the number of hotels where the minimum price of their rooms is between the price range.

```
SELECT c.category_name, count( DISTINCT id_hotel ) , min( price ) min_price
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN hotels w ON ( c.id_category = w.category_id ) 
LEFT JOIN (
hotels_room_types
INNER JOIN hotels_room_types_seasons ON hotels_room_types.id_hotels_room_types = hotels_room_types_seasons.hotels_room_types_id) 
ON w.id_hotel = hotels_room_types.hotel_id
GROUP BY c.category_name
HAVING min_price >=10 AND min_price <=130
```

Could anyone help me how to write the appropriate query?
Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't see how you are applying any specific season.  Your minimum price for one hotel could be $100 non-peak season and $400 peak season.  Also, do you really want the minimum price? and not the maximum price?  If I were being cautious on spending, I would want to know the HIGHEST price I COULD get hit with and know there were rates lower than that, but MIN() also works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  Categories.Name, COUNT(DISTINCT ID_Hotel) [Count]
FROM    Hotels
        INNER JOIN Categories
            ON Category_ID = ID_Category
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  Hotel_ID, MIN(Price) [LowestPrice]
            FROM    hotels_room_types
                    INNER JOIN hotels_room_types_seasons
                        ON id_hotels_room_type = hotels_room_types_id
            -- CONSIDER FILTERING BY SEASON HERE
            GROUP BY Hotel_ID
        ) price
            ON price.Hotel_ID = Hotels.ID_Hotel
WHERE   LowestPrice BETWEEN 10 AND 130 -- OR WHATEVER YOUR PARAMETERS ARE
GROUP BY Categories.Name
```

I have no idea what RDBMS you are using but I do not know any where your query would work. The problem you were having with the Min Price (I assume) is because you are applying the logic after grouping by category, so you are counting all hotels where the category has a lowest price between 10 and 130, not where the hotel has a room with the lowest price between 10 and 130.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
      c.Category_name,
      count(*) NumHotels
   from
      ( select distinct
              byRoomType.hotel_id
           from
              hotels_room_types_seasons bySeason
                 join hotels_room_types byRoomType
                    on bySeason.hotels_room_types_id = byRoomType.id_hotels_room_type
           where
              bySeason.Price between LowPriceParameter and HighPriceParameter 
      ) QualifiedHotels

         join Hotels
            on QualifiedHotels.hotel_id = Hotels.id_hotel

            join Categories c
               on category_id = c.id_category
```